# Counting records in db

Tags: php, kohana

I use

```
public function get_all_news()
{
    $result = DB::select()
            ->from("parys_news")
            ->order_by("ID", "DESC")
            ->execute()
            ;

    return $result;
}
```

to create a query. Now I want to make a similar function for counting a records from the query

```
public function count_records($query)
{


}
```

how to do that in Kohana?

Answer (score -1):

In you particular case to get the count of all news count you can simply call [`Database_Result::count()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Database_Result#count) method on the returned result object, e.g.:

```
$news = YourModel->get_all_news();
$news_count = $news->count();
```

If you want to have a universal `count_records($query)` method, then depending on what parameter you want to pass:

- if it's simple SQL query string:

  ```
  public function count_records($query)
  {
      return DB::query(Database::SELECT, $query)->execute()->count();
  }
  ```
- if it's a Database_Query

  ```
  public function count_records(Database_Query $query)
  {
      return $query->execute()->count();
  }
  ```
- or of it's already the Database_Result object, then simply:

  ```
  public function count_records(Database_Result $result)
  {
      return $result->count();
  }
  ```